# how to create table which has a column from another table in mySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

i want to create a table :

> products

which looks like
(these are columns name)

**Id Name Category-id Description**

now Category-id column gets the values from another table

> category

which looks like

**`Id Name Description`**

now category.Id is used in products.Category-id

how to do this in mySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is called a VIEW in SQL parlance. That is, a virtual table, created dynamically based on a SELECT statement. I would do it like this:

```
CREATE VIEW product_with_cat AS
SELECT p.Id, p.Name, c.Name as Category, c.Description as Category_desc
FROM products p INNER JOIN category c ON p.Category_id = c.Id;
```

Comment: This is generic SQL, so it can be used in most SQL flavors. See the complete manual for how to use CREATE VIEW in MySQL here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that catedory-id is the link between the two tables. In that case you may want to read about `FOREIGN KEY`. For example, [see here](http://www.ehow.com/way_5247249_mysql-foreign-key-tutorial.html)